# Laravel upload image error

Tags: laravel

Error: The image must be a file of type: jpeg, png, jpg, gif, svg.

I have this error when i try to upload image from the form, the image is .jpeg and i think it should work beacuse 'image'should be 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'

**My Controller**

```
public function store(){

    $this->validate(request(),[

        'title' => 'required',

        'image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',

        'body' => 'required',

    ]);

    auth()->user()->publish(

        new Post(request(['title','image','body']))
    );


    session()->flash('message', 'your post has now been published');


    return redirect('/');
}
```

** My BLADE**

```
<form method="POST" action="/posts">

    {{csrf_field()}}

    <div class="form-group">

        <label for="title">Titolo</label>

        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title">

    </div>


    <div class="form-group">

        <label for="image">Immagine</label>

        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="image" name="image">

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

        <label for="body">Corpo</label>

        <textarea id="body" name="body" class="form-control"></textarea>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

        <button type="submit" class="bottone">Invia</button>

    </div>

    @include ('layouts.errors')

</form>
```

Comment: is this actual error message?

Comment: form type must be *'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'*

Comment: @arunkumar ok now it works but none file uploaded into db

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#storing-files refer this to upload files

Comment: @arunkumar i have added new route Storage::putFile('photos', new File('img')); but if i try to open the homepage i got  The file "img" does not exist

Comment: tryu required|image......

Answer (score 8):

You are missing enctype="multipart/form-data"
Your codes are fine. But anyway I recommend to use `image - intervention`.

Answer (score 1):

Add multipart support in your form just like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="/posts" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do something like this:

```
<!-- Controller -->

<?php
public function store(Request $request) {

    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' =>  'required',
        'image' =>  'image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        'body'  =>  'required'
    ]);

    auth()->user()->publish(
        Storage::putFile('photos', new File($request['image']), 'public');
        new Post($request['title', 'image', 'body']);
    );

    session()->flash('message', 'your post has now been published');

    return redirect('/');
}

?>

<!-- routes -->

<?php

Route::post('/posts', controllerName::store());

?>

<!-- Blade -->
<?

     <form method="POST" action="/posts" enctype="multipart/form-data">

           {{csrf_field()}}

           <div class="form-group">

             <label for="title">Titolo</label>

           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title">

           </div>


      <div class="form-group">

  <label for="image">Immagine</label>

  <input type="file" class="form-control" id="image" name="image">

</div>

<div class="form-group">

  <label for="body">Corpo</label>

  <textarea id="body" name="body" class="form-control"></textarea>

</div>

<div class="form-group">

  <button type="submit" class="bottone">Invia</button>

</div>

  @include ('layouts.errors')

        </form>

?>
```

#### I haven't tested it, wrote it on my phone.

Comment: Did you change 'controllerName' to the name of your controller where the store function is in?

Comment: yes, Route::post('/posts', PostsController::store());

Comment: And a screenshot?

Comment: Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Class 'PostsController' not found

Answer (score 0):

```
$request->validate([
        'N_image1' => 'required | mimes : jpg, png,PNG, JPG, JPEG, GIF, SVG, jpeg, svg | max : 2184',
        'N_image2' => 'required |  mimes : jpg, png, jpeg, svg | max : 1245',
        'N_image3' => 'required | mimes : jpg, png, jpeg, svg | max : 1245',
        'N_image4' => 'required | mimes : jpg, png, jpeg, svg | max : 1245',
        'N_image5' => 'required | mimes : jpg, png, jpeg, svg | max : 1245',
    ]);
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, the **how** is important, but much of the site's quality level comes from people going out of their way to explain **why**. While a _code-only_ answer get the person who asked the question past whatever hurdle they might be facing, it doesn't do them or future visitors much good in the long run. See [Is there any benefit in code-only answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/183937)